# proof verification $\left \| f-p \right \|_{\infty }<\varepsilon $ and $\left \| {f}'-{p}' \right \|_{\infty }<\varepsilon $

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

$f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and differentiable, show that for every $\varepsilon >0 $ it exists a polynomial $p$ such that  $\left \| f-p \right \|_{\infty }<\varepsilon $ and  $\left \| {f}'-{p}' \right \|_{\infty }<\varepsilon $

proof:

since $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous from the Stone-weierstrass theorem we know it exist a polynomial sequence  $p_n$ such that $p_n \xrightarrow[]{uni}f$ so it exist a $n_0 \in\mathbb{N}$  $\left \| f-p_{n_0} \right \|_{\infty }<\varepsilon $ consider  $p_{n_0}=p \Rightarrow $ we have  $\left \| f-p \right \|_{\infty }<\varepsilon/2 (1)$ so if $x_0 \in[0,1]$ such that $\left \| p(x_0)-f(x_0) \right \|_{\infty }<\varepsilon/2 (2)$

$(1)+(2)$   $\left \| f-p \right \|_{\infty }+ \left \| p(x_0)-f(x_0) \right \|_{\infty }<\varepsilon   $

$\left \| (f(x)-f(x_0))-(p(x)-p(x_0))  \right \|\leq $  $\left \| f-p \right \|_{\infty }+ \left \| p(x_0)-f(x_0) \right \|_{\infty }<\varepsilon   $

then if  $\frac{1}{x-x_0} \leq1 \Rightarrow $ $\left \| \frac{(f(x)-f(x_0))}{x-x_0}-\frac{(p(x)-p(x_0))}{x-x_0}  \right \|=\left \| {f}'-{p}' \right \|_{\infty }< \varepsilon$

Comment: The last line has a few assertions that need work (for example, dividing by a number less than or equal to 1 can increase the value of the thing you're dividing by, and there is no reason to expect equality between the difference quotients you identify and "f'" and "p'" (the values seem to vanish from the problem). I haven't thought carefully but my intuition would be to start with a Stone-Weierstrass polynomial approximation to f' and integrate it, because as a general slogan, integration always makes things easier than differentiation does.

Comment: If I integrate how will the derivative will come up to the inequality i don't see how I can use this. Should I make somehow a contradiction by assuming that $\left \| {f}'-{p}' \right \|\geq \varepsilon $

Comment: My thought is that f(x) - p(x) is the integral from 0 to x of something that you might be able to make small by approximating f' appropriately, and the integral of something small over a small interval is also small. I have not worked the details out. Good luck

Comment: Start from $p'$ a $\varepsilon$-accurate approximant of $f'$, then select $p(x)=f(x)$ at whatever particular $x$ ($0$, say). Then the inequality you want for $f$ will follow by integration and some simple estimation. (This is basically what leslie townes said.)

Comment: Ok I think I get what both of you saying I will work on it and come back here with an answer thank you.

Comment: Is my proof ok ?

Answer (score 1):

Since ${f}'$ is continuous (it is i checked again the original problem) frome S-W theorem we have $q_n\xrightarrow[]{uni} {f}'\Rightarrow  \left \|q_n- {f}'  \right \|< \varepsilon 
 $ lets call $q_n={p_n}'$ from before we saw that

$\left | {f}'-{p}' \right |< \varepsilon \Rightarrow  \int_{0}^{1}\left | {f}'-{p}' \right |dx<\varepsilon \Rightarrow \left | \int_{0}^{1}{f}'-{p}'dx \right |\leq \int_{0}^{1}\left | {f}'-{p}' \right |dx< \varepsilon$

$\left | \int_{0}^{1}{f}'-{p}'dx \right |=\left | f-p \right |$

Comment: @José Carlos Santos , because you are answering most of my post, which i am very grateful for that, I thought I could tag you here to check on this solution. Thanks in advance.